# Automating a website using Python webdriver. Retrieve IP value of a virtual machine using ifconfig command

Tags: python, automation, webdriver

## We are automating a website using Python web driver. In that website we have to create a virtual machine and access the canvas of that virtual machine. We have to check the IP address of that virtual machine using the ifconfig command. I am able to send IFCONFIG command to the canvas but I am unable to retrieve the output of ifconfig.

```
# selecting the vm canvas
`ft=driver.find_element_by_id("noVNC_screen").find_element_by_id("noVNC_canvas")'

time.sleep(20)
ft.send_keys("root") #sending user name
ft.send_keys(webdriver.common.keys.Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
ft.send_keys("secret")  # sending password
ft.send_keys(webdriver.common.keys.Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(10)
ft.send_keys("ifconfig") # sending ifconfig command to canvas
time.sleep(3)
ft.send_keys(webdriver.common.keys.Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)   

driver.close()
```

**after sending ifconfig command it displaying the output on canvas . But i have to check through script whether ip is coming or not to that vm, for that i want the output of ifconfig to a file or variable.....**

**please give me a solution to do this...**
Thank you..

Comment: your code snippet please?

Comment: When you say "Python web driver" -- you mean [Selenium WebDriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html), right?